# How to run only the snapshot tests of a Vue project

Tags: unit-testing, webpack, vuejs2, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I implemented unit and snapshot tests for my Vue.js project. Now I want to run unit and snapshot test separately (to integrate them into separate gitlab CI jobs).

By runing the following command both unit and snapshot tests execute:
`vue-cli-service test:unit`

I used the following documentation to implement the snapshot tests: 
https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/testing-single-file-components-with-jest.html#snapshot-testing

Comment: I use the default `vue init webpack` setup

Comment: I am was able to run only the snapshot test with the following jest cli option:
`npm run test:unit -- --testNamePattern=.*snapshot$`
see also: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli#testnamepattern-regex